# Dynamic parameter selection on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a build/deploy job on jenkins, and user can select multiple items to be deployed with multi select parameter. I retrieve those values dynamically from db table with a groovy script.

Problem is that some of the variables should be linked. Meaning; when user selects item X, item A and item B also should be selected.

Is there a way of triggering a selection event on jenkins multi select? or should I use something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time I found a way to do this using [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin)

1- I kept my initial `extended choice parameter` lets name it **COMPONENTLIST**

2- Then I created another paramateter as `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter` lets name it **COMPONENT_IDS**

2a- I added **COMPONENTLIST** as `referenced parameter` in COMPONENT_IDS. And set the `Choice Type` as `Formatted HTML` and also selected `Omit value field`

2b- I used following groovy script to collect initial selection and make modifications on it and returned as in step 2c

```
def output = COMPONENTLIST.split(',').collect{it as int}
```

2c- tricky part here! It is different how you pass the paramater to build stage. Following line helped me to pass COMPONENT_IDS to build.

```
output = output.join(",") 
return "<b>${output}</b><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"value\" value=\"${output}\" />"
```